# Content addressable memory chip

Tags: memory

I have searched a lot for a content addressable memory chip, but I couldn't find any part numbers. Why aren't there any chips for this kind of memory?!

Comment: You're looking in the wrong databooks. Try some from the late 1980s or early 1990s.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - which sort-of implies that they were never really used for much ...

Comment: Definite niche. Can't find the AMD one, but found this https://www.engineeringspecifier.com/around-the-industry/music-semiconductors-revolutionizes-cam-market-with-new-harrp-product-line

Comment: Also found a Synchronous one, though it might be a SCAM. https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/326/NL82721.php

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am looking in Mouser and Digikey. There is only one CAM in the memory section of Digikey. Also, no distributor has NL82721!

Comment: I used CAM devices many years ago (1999 or so) as a switch routing device - I believe they were quite common at the time, but have since been overtaken by more power and space efficient methods.

Answer (score 2):

Because there never was an application that required enough chips in a fixed configuration to justify producing a standard chip.

Generally speaking, each application requires a unique configuration, and it usually makes more sense to integrate the CAM with other application-specific logic in an ASIC.

Comment: Or with an FPGA too.

Comment: What do you mean by the configuration? What specific configuration does a CAM have except its data width and depth?

Comment: FPGA. About that... I found a Xilinx datasheet (DS253, PDF) dated 2008. And marked "Discontinued IP". :-( In a locked filing cabinet, in a disused broom cupboard at the bottom of the stairs.

Comment: I seem to recall Signetics having one in their databook at one time.  An idea from the past that never seemed to be viable in the market.

Comment: CAMs are still in wide use, actually - but they are built into specialised ASICs instead of being available as discrete components.  For example, the tag memory of a set-associative cache is a small (and very fast) CAM.